# Why do SSD drives get so much more expensive as they get larger?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Normal HDD costs go up very little as drives get larger. For example, an average 1TB drive costs a little under $90, 2TB costs a little over $100, and a 3TB drive costs close to $150. For HDDs, the cost per GB goes *down* as the number of GB goes up.

SSD costs don't work like this: a 128GB SSD goes for $120ish, 256GB goes for $250ish, and 512GB drives get up to $600. The cost per GB goes *up* as the number of GB rises.

What is it about SSDs that makes them so much costlier as they get larger?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/sql-on-ssds-hot-crazy-love/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already pointed you to the great video [SQL on SSDs: Hot and Crazy Love](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/sql-on-ssds-hot-crazy-love/) from which I will also draw my answer.

The cost of an SSD isn't so heavily tied to the actual storage media, but to the parts that manage that storage. Larger SSDs require more sophisticated controllers to be able to address that storage.

Comment: I'd also imagine supply and demand also has something to do with it, more people buying the SSDs with lower storage.

Though it doesn't seem to be the case that larger SSDs are always more expensive per GB. Crucial's M4 on Amazon is cheaper per GB the larger you go (64GB -> 128GB -> 256GB -> 512GB, for example.

Comment: -1 This answer is not correct in this size-range consumer SSDs. The 128GB to 512GB range all use the same controllers, just different amount of storage media. It is only once you go above 512GB that you have to start using more complex controller schemes.

Comment: @MrAlpha: So it's just supply and demand?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I suspect the biggest factor is that the kind of person willing to spend money on a 512GB SSD isn't the penny pinching kind in the first place. Or put differently, the people getting the biggest and best hardware aren't the price conscious. That said, I did see a Crucial m4 512GB for under $400 the other day, so prices are coming down.